# Why Virtual Box shows higher single core score than on the host CPU itself?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, performance

Virtual Box 6.1 running latest Linux Manjaro Host is Windows 10 professional. The PC is intel Intel Core i9-12900K with 16 cores and 128 GB.

My Virtual Box setting is to use 50 GB of RAM and 8 cores.

I also made sure to disable Hyper-V on Windows 10 to get best performance from Virtual Box.

I run same Geekbench CPU test, one time inside Virtual Box running linux and the single core score was **2022**.

Then downloaded the same Geekbench software and run same CPU test directly in Windows 10, and it now gives score **1745**.

The following are direct links to each full report result.

- On Virtual Box: https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/17191867
- On Windows 10: https://browser.geekbench.com/v5/cpu/17199466

> [image]

The score for Multi-core is higher on Windows, because it has 16 cores, but my setting for Virtual Box only was assigned 8 cores. So I can understand that multi-core score will be higher on the host windows than the guest.

My question is, why does Virtual Box scores higher on same test than the host itself? I would have expected running on a bar machine will produce better performance. This is surprising.

Does this mean Linux is faster than Windows 10 even when running inside a Virtual Box? So if I replace Windows with Linux on the same PC, this score will be even higher than it is now when using Linux in Virtual Box?

Screen shots for my Virtual Box settings. KVM is used for virtualization.

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

**Update**

To reply to comment below

> Can you check if the VM CPU support AV512?

The following is the information from inside the Linux running on the Virtual box

```
>cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 151
model name  : 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K
stepping    : 2
cpu MHz     : 3187.200
cache size  : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 8
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 22
wp      : yes

    flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca 
cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm 
constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni 
pclmulqdq vmx ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt aes xsave 
avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single tpr_shadow 
vnmi flexpriority vpid fsgsbase avx2 invpcid rdseed clflushopt md_clear 
flush_l1d arch_capabilities

vmx flags   : vnmi flexpriority tsc_offset vtpr vapic
bugs        : spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass swapgs
bogomips    : 6376.00
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: With so many cores a single core might be fully reserved for the VM and a single thread test might have no overhead by the OS and VM operations and schedulers. If you made the same test while in parallel you see a video what could be the result?

Comment: ```Does this mean Linux is faster than Windows 10 even when running inside a Virtual Box?``` - in some cases absolutely! Filesystem metadata operations like fopen/flock/fseek/fclose are in the neighborhood of ~50-100 times faster in a linux virtual machine compared to windows 10 bare metal (one example: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/vm1oy8/comment/ie1idaj/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3  , but i've seen plenty more, and its been like that for YEARS, all the way back to Windows XP i think?)

Comment: @hanshenrik The Reddit comment that you linked says "it'll take a second on Linux, it'll take like a minute in Windows", but they clearly didn't run their own code, because neither MSVC nor MinGW has `flock`. They are probably remembering some performance problem they had at some time in the past, and who knows what the actual code or timings were. Anyway, this has nothing to do with Geekbench, which is a CPU benchmark.

Comment: @benrg actually WinApi has flock, but its called [LockFileEx](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-lockfileex), LOCK_SH=> 0, LOCK_EX =>  LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK, LOCK_NB => LOCKFILE_FAIL_IMMEDIATELY. but it's not just a past performance problem, just opening/closing files is _MUCH_ slower on Windows/WSL than Linux. but yeah that's not related to a CPU benchmark

Comment: @hanshenrik I'm just pointing out that he didn't run the code he wrote down, so there's no reason to believe his numbers (vague as they are). Also, his benchmark without the `flock` calls completes in about 1 second on Windows.

Comment: Can you check if the VM CPU support AV512? AVX512 is known to perform worse than AVX256 and I think geekbench uses it but virtualbox doesn't seem to support it.

Comment: @user3528438  How do I check that the Virtual Box I am using supports AVX512 or not?

Comment: cat /proc/cpuinfo ?

Comment: @user3528438 I updated the post with the information you requested.

Comment: Just another idea: What about mitigations maybe?

Answer (score 14):

There is a long discussion about this [on the Geekbench forum](http://support.primatelabs.com/discussions/geekbench/17050-linux-vs-windows-results). From that discussion, it is pretty clear that you cannot expect to compare Windows and Linux scores against each other, though it is unclear exactly why this is true.

> Thanks for letting us know about this, and I apologize for the delayed response. The deviation in scores for those two configurations are slightly larger than normal, but not atypical for the difference between two runs on a given machine. Some specific workload scores, mainly the HTML5 DOM score, show an unexpected discrepancy which could be the result of a hardware issue or an intermittent background process, though with two results it is difficult to draw firm conclusions about its cause.
>
> Linux and Windows do not use the same compiler. Some details on the compilers used for each platform are available via our page on the individual Geekbench 4 CPU workloads. Currently, there are no plans to change how Geekbench is compiled on a particular platform. Despite the different compilers, Geekbench should generate similar scores for the same hardware on average, though scores may fluctuate slightly.

Comment: different compilers, memory allocators, background noise, can cause significant differences sometimes

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 vs. clang 3.9.1 (release date 2017). So not only are they using a newer compiler for Linux, clang in my experience also produces a higher quality machine code than MSVC does.

Comment: In addition, another factor is that the CPU has to keep inside the total power envelope. Many CPU's can run at a higher clock frequency when only some of the cores are loaded - so you may see a much higher rating on a single thread.

Comment: This answer suggests the difference is between the OSes, not the VirtualBox itself. Could you try running Windows inside VirtualBox and compare with the bare metal Windows run? @nasser

Comment: @vidarlo: That's why Geekbench tests single-threaded performance separately.  If it was just taking the per-thread performance of the multi-threaded test, then yes the different would be even bigger, with competition between hyper-threads sharing a physical core, as well as thermal limits on max turbo on single-core vs. all-cores.  (Or from some of the threads having to run on E-cores on this Alder Lake system, since they actually have 8c16t P-cores and 8 E cores, for a total of 24 logical cores)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that that Linux has some optimizations for virtualizing Linux. So if you run KVM/QEMU as a hypervisor there will be less overhead when virtualizing Linux as a host as opposed to when virtualizing windows as a host.

So Virtual Box may also be more optimized for Linux emulation than Windows. I would try running the benchmark on both systems without the virtualization layer and compare the results.